# multi-class support vector machine classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

i try to run own svm-code using one against one but i have an error in selected function for best (c,sigma) and an error in plot function ,i hope to give me your hand,and this is code

```
clear
clc
close all
%load the data
load dataset
load spacies
[~,~,group] = unique(spacies);
data=dataset(1:12,1:19);
xdata=zscore(data);
%group=spacies(1:end,1);
p=0.5;
[train,test]=crossvalind('HoldOut',group,p);
trainingsample=xdata(train,:);
traininglabel=group(train,1);
testingsample=xdata(test,:);
testinglabel=group(test,1);
numclass=max(group);
for i=1:numclass
    for j=i+1:numclass
        inij=(traininglabel==i)|(traininglabel==j);
        trainingsampleij=trainingsample(inij,:);
        traininglabelij=traininglabel(inij,:);
        %%k-fold using training data
        numfold=8;
        indices=crossvalind('kfold',traininglabelij,numfold);
        sigma=2.^(-10:1:10);
        C=2.^(-5:1:5);
        [bestsigma,bestC]=BestParametersRBF(trainingsampleij,...
                           traininglabelij,sigma,C,indices,numfold);
        %%performance
        svmStruct=svmtrain(trainingsampleij,traininglabelij,...
             'showplot',true,'kernel_function','rbf','rbf_sigma',bestsigma,...
             'boxconstraint',bestC);
        title(sprintf('Kernel Function: %s','rbf',...
              func2str(svmStruct.KernelFunction)),...
                       'interpreter','none');
        classes=svmclassify(svmStruct,testingsample,'showplot',true);
     end
 end
 acc=mean(grp2idx(classes)==grp2idx(testinglabel));
```

Comment: you could get answer by simply googling it http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Answer (score 1):

Training data is the data used to train you classifier (for example SVM).

Test data is used to test the performance of the trained classifier.

Comment: thank you GilLevi...but can you tell me how can i make the test and train from a matrix input (1 rawx3600columns)?

Comment: I don't quite understand how your data is organized. Please explain.

Comment: hi GilLevi..can you help me to find the error in my code above

Answer (score 0):

Both consist a set of (x, y) pairs, where x is the input vector and y is the output(like the class which x belongs to). But they are different on usage and application stage.

The training data is used to determine the value of the parameters of your model(and sometimes the form of the model), when the value of parameters is not fixed.

The test data is used when the parameters have been totally fixed, to test your model's quality(like precision or recall). Strictly speaking, you can not use test data to adjust any parameters, include the model complexity parameters. Test data is only used to *test*.

The development dataset(usually seperated from training set) is used to adjust the model complexity parameters.

Comment: thanks Zhang Bo so much ...and what is the mean of spacies in data and how can i create it